# Solving a cubic inequality

Tags: inequality

$4x^3 - 3x^2 + x \ge 0$ , solve the inequality:

My solution for this question:

$x(4x^2-3x+1) \ge 0 $

$4x^2 - 3x + 1$ is not solvable, assume $x \in \mathbb R$

So $x \ge 0$ and  $x \in \mathbb R$

$x \le 0$ and  $x \in \mathbb R$

So answer is  $x \in \mathbb R$.... which is wrong

Not sure why classpad says the answer $x\ge0$

Comment: You've observed that $x(4x^2 - 3x + 1)$ is the product of $x$ and a positive number, so that that product is nonnegative iff $x \geq 0$.

Comment: oooh so is more like common sense? thinking of ab>0, solving by a>0 and b>0 ,  OR a<0 b<0

Comment: but because this case b is belongs to R, so a <\ 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be clearer if you write it as
$$x(4x^2-3x+1) = x\cdot \left(4(x-\tfrac38)^2 +\tfrac7{16}\right)$$
Hence the quadratic factor is always positive, and can be cancelled from both sides of the inequality.

Comment: i did tried this method but i got x(4(x-3/8)^2+55/64) >= 0

Comment: and still can't square root negative number because it must be real

Comment: You don't actually have to solve for $x$.  All you need to recognize is that the quadratic is invariably positive.  Further, check your calculations.

Comment: by the way thanks for making my question prettier

Answer (score 0):

we can write $x(4x^2-3x+1)\geq 0$ and we have $$4x(x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{4})\geq 0$$this is true since $$x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{4}=(x-3/8)^2+\frac{17}{64}\geq 0$$

Comment: moving the constant to other side and square root it, i will be imaginary number ...

Answer (score 0):

Another way of viewing the matter of the "irreducible" (not factorable in $ \ \mathbb{R} \ $ ) quadratic polynomial (determined, say, by calculating its discriminant) is that its curve thus has no $ \ x-$ intercepts.  So the curve is always either "above" or "below" the $ \ x-$ axis .   Since this factor equals 1  for  $ \  x \ = \ 0 \ $ , this tells us that the factor is *always* positive.  The sign of the left-hand side of the inequality is thus completely determined by the other factor, $ \ x  \ $ .